# The distance between the browser and design

Tags: menu, html, spacing

```
#menu{ background:#555;
   display: block;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   border-bottom:5px solid #CC3333;

}
```

i want remove spacing between the menu and the start web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*    /*Works for Non IE or IE 9 or +*/
{
margin:0;
}

for IE based & non IE both works on almost all versions

body
{
 margin:0px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all that is on the page there is probably a padding being implemented on the element containing the menu.

Try doing a CSS reset first.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

add that to the top of your CSS file and link to it from the HTML page.